# How to fetch list of files under one folder in adls gen 2

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory, azure-databricks, azure-data-lake-gen2

I have requirement like daily i am receiving diffrent type of files like Excel,CSV,Avaro,JSON etc

1. I need to fetch list of files names like
   tablea.xls
   tablea.csv etc
2. I need convert all the file from different format to CSV.

This things we need to do using ADF.

Thanks ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Get Metadata](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-get-metadata-activity) activity to list files and the [Copy activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-overview) to convert the format.  Copy can change formats but can not do much in the way of transform.  Specify the format you want in the Sink section of the Copy config.  Try some things out and [some tutorials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-tutorials) and come back if you get specific errors.